# User authentication for overlay http application on top of SQL

Tags: sql, http, authentication

What would be the best way to authenticate a user in accessing a backend sql database where I do not have access to that SQL database password. If I hash and store the submitted password in a separate SQL database I cannot then use it to access the backend database since I cannot unhash it. I am currently storing credentials in cookies which I know is unsafe.

Comment: I want the user to use the same SQL password to sign in to avoid signing in separately each time a button is clicked to access the SQL database which is hosted remotely. This is an internal website and not internet facing.

Comment: Why don't you know this SQL database password ?

Comment: @WaLinke consider this..  I have an SQL database and I receive a username and password from html form..  how would I then reuse the username and password submitted by the form until session expires.